# How to get field value in django Model?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have this code:

```
class Book(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=70)
    author = models.CharField(max_length=70)
    rating = models.IntegerField(default=None)
    volume = models.IntegerField(null=True, default=None)
    annotation = models.TextField(default=None)
    year = models.IntegerField()
```

I want to get a value from field right in class. For example, "Harry Potter" for name. I don't find method to do it.

Comment: You need to use `Book.objects.get()` or `Book.objects.filter()` to get _instances_ of the model.  Then once you have those, you can access the `.name` field on each instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, you have to show names, that's why you want to access in class.

You can make use of [`__str__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__str__)<sup>[python-doc]</sup> for displaying names.

Try below code:

```py
class Book(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=70)
    author = models.CharField(max_length=70)
    rating = models.IntegerField(default=None)
    volume = models.IntegerField(null=True, default=None)
    annotation = models.TextField(default=None)
    year = models.IntegerField()
    
    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.name}"
```

> **Remember:** `__str__` method requires data of `str` type.